# Парсер sql-запроса

Tags: c#, запрос, парсер, sql-server, visual-studio

Привет.

Существует ли бесплатный parser sql запроса?

Из запроса хотелось бы вытащить хотя бы имена параметров и используемые таблицы.

Среда разработки: Visual Studio, C#
СУБД: MS SQL

Comment: А вам точно нужен сырой SQL?

Comment: Грубо говоря, беру из файла sql запросы, некоторые из них с параметрами, мне нужно проверить валидность этих запросов, единственной что пришло мне в голову, так это проверить существуют ли таблицы, которые используются запросами.

P.s. Также нужно знать имена входных параметров.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если запрос уже есть, то все знает сервер: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677185(v=sql.110).aspx и другие.

Comment: А если запрос заранее не известен?
К примеру, для получения информации из БД используются процедуры и обычные sql запросы, мне нужно их проверить, но процедуры и запросы могут иметь входные параметры, поэтому осуществить их проверку банальным выполнением не получится.

Если в sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities передать имя процедуры, то вернутся все сущности, от которых зависит процедура, либо ошибка, если таких сущностей. Как раз то, что мне нужно.

Но как быть с обычными запросами, создать из них процедуру не могу, нет прав, выполнить тоже не могу, так что делать тогда?)

Comment: Тогда смотрите на объектную модель, там должно быть.